# Find the highest number in array , using while or for?

Tags: c#, arrays

Please a i have a Questions , I need find the higghest value in array. To the array will people write name (textbox1) and money (texbox2). I have 2 buttons first button is save to the array and second write the name with the biggest money.

**Code for save:**

```
    string[] name = new string[50];
    int items = 0;
    int[] money = new int[50];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            name[items] = textBox1.Text;
            money[items] = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            items++;        
        }
    }
```

**And to the button2 need search the biggest value and write name! Please help me**

Comment: Sort the array and then get the value of the last item.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Your try/catch looks a little fishy to me - I don't think that will do what you expect.

Comment: @DaveZych That's a pretty poor way to get the max value.  You only need to do a linear search.

Comment: Keep you names and money as Dictionary.

Comment: @PetrNikolkyMedvídek - When you are totally lost on an assignment, it's probably a good idea to ask your teacher for help.  That way they will know where students are getting stuck and what topics need to be covered in more detail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Array Maximum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932148/c-sharp-array-maximum)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    int maxIndex = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        if (money[i] > money[maxIndex])            
            maxIndex = i;            
    }

    MessageBox.Show(name[maxIndex] + " has biggest value " + money[maxIndex]);
 }
```

Comment: @PetrNikolkyMedvídek btw if it is a homework, then I think you should add appropriate tag to question (this advice also for your future questions)

Comment: No I need this program for FIFA13 score with play friend.

Answer (score 3):

To get the Max int from your array you can use [IEnumerable.Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535031.aspx):

```
money.Max();
```

But there could be more than one name with the same high money value, perhaps you need to handle this also, I think Dictionary would be your best option

```
private Dictionary<string, int> Names = new Dictionary<string, int>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int value = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out value))
    {
        if (!Names.ContainsKey(textBox1.Text))
        {
            Names.Add(textBox1.Text, value);
        }
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Names.Any())
    {
        int maxMoney = Names.Max(v => v.Value);
        var names = Names.Where(k => k.Value.Equals(maxMoney));
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            // Names with the highest money value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One possible issue is `Max/Min` require at least on element :( So be aware of that edge-case, otherwise LINQ is indeed nice for this.